# Выполнение скриптов после innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю модальное окно входа на чистом JS
При axios ответе вставляю содержимое страницы модального окна

```
thisModal.querySelector('.modal-content').innerHTML = response.data
```

Все хорошо работает, но в содержимом страницы содержится не только html форма входа, а еще и скрипты проверки отправленных значений и тд и они не работают (

```
<form>
...
</form>
<script>
...
</script>
```

Когда все разрабатывал на jquery достаточно было

```
$('#modal-login .modal-content').html(data);
```

и все скрипты со страницы загружались и работали в модальном окне, есть ли способ сделать то же самое на Vanilla JS

Comment: Вас наверное заинтересует эти методы https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML и https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement. А про то почему `innerHTML` не выполняет скрипты, можете прочитать тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Эти методы никак не решают проблему ...